# How to get modelAttribute values that are not in form, in Spring

Tags: java, spring, forms, hibernate, modelattribute

I have an hibernate entity object. I need to update this object, so I passed this object to a form. In the form i will change some values and the others are constant. And I can not show these constant values to the client, so they should pass to next page via another method except from diplaying them explicity in a html form.

Here is my object obtained in controller and passed to the view:

```
@GetMapping("/update")
public String update(@RequestParam("dataId") int id, Model md){
    Doctor dr = doctorService.getById(id);


    /*for example lets say this doctor object has following properties
    dr.setId(3);
    dr.setName("James");
    dr.setUserId(7);
     */

    md.addAttribute("doctor", dr);


    return "object-form";
}
```

Here is my form in view :

```
<form:form action="save" modelAttribute="doctor" method="post">

    <form:errors path="name"></form:errors>
    <form:input path="name" placeholder="Doktor İsmi" class="form-control" />

    <form:hidden path="id" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save doc" />
</form:form>
```

From form, only **name** and **id** values are coming, however, the **userId** is null. I need to get this userId without post.

Here is my post-process controller that I handle the object:

```
@PostMapping(value="/save")
public String save(@Valid Doctor dr,  BindingResult bindingResult){

    doctorValidator.validate(dr, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "object-form";
    }
    else{
        doctorService.save(dr);
        return "redirect:list";
    }
}
```

I don't know how can achieve this r even there is way for it. I searched on Google but I did not find any solution.

Thank a lot,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get previous doctor object from db and get the user ID from there like below:

```
@PostMapping(value="/save")
public String save(@Valid Doctor dr,  BindingResult bindingResult){
    Doctor prevDr = doctorService.getById(dr.getId());
    dr.setUserId(prevDr.getUserId());
    doctorValidator.validate(dr, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "object-form";
    }
    else{
        doctorService.save(dr);
        return "redirect:list";
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves my problem but I am not sure if this is good practice, Actually I am trying to implement a basic update operation. Is this the standart way to do this? (I am a beginner of hibernate and spring)

Comment: If you have no farther work with userId, then the good practice would be to create a model class for your form. And while updating, create entity object from that form model object and save it. This will update the rows with new values and will retain other(userId ins this case) that are not set from form. This will save you one extra select query in your db.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds better. One more point :how can I pass the view-model object from show-update-form method to save method of controller class for assigning it ot the hiberanate entity?

Comment: This is similar what you are doing currently. Instead of adding the model attribute doctor add the new model object by copying values from doctor and show it in form and get it back in post controller, now create entity from the model object and save the entity object.

Comment: Thank a lot sir, I will do that